# Can anyone explain to me why I Eclipse is claiming an invalid tag, yet the JSP seems to be working

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp

Here is my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<c:set var="root" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"></c:set>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Create Seats</title>
</head>
<body>

        <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
            <c:forEach var="seatlessEmployee" items="${seatlessEmployeesList}" varStatus="loopCount">
            <form method="POST" action="${root}/create.do">
                <tr>
                    <td>${seatlessEmployee.employeeID }</td>
                    <td>${seatlessEmployee.firstName }</td>
                    <td>${seatlessEmployee.lastName }</td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="emptySeatID">
                            <c:forEach var="emptySeat" items="${emptySeatsList}">
                                <option value="${emptySeat.seatID }">${emptySeat.seatName }
                            </c:forEach>    
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" value="${seatlessEmployee.employeeID }" name="seatlessEmployeeID"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </form>
            </c:forEach>
        </table>

</body>
</html>
```

Eclipe is claiming that the opening tr tag is in an invalid location.
This seems to be absurd as the page is rendering properly when I run it

Comment: If there is one thing I've learnt about Eclipse when I was using it, it's that is JSP validator can't be trusted at all. That said, it's right here: you can't have a form as a child of a table.

Answer (score 1):

The warnings you see are generated when your validator comes across content that it doesn't expect according to the content model for a tag.
I suggest turning off HTML/jsp validation. The HTML/jsp validator is pretty picky.

Answer (score 1):

Eclipse is right and your browser will try to guess where to put things. You can't just randomly wrap elements in form elements and expect uniform rendering across browsers. Form's are not valid direct child elements of tables. A valid layout would be:

```
<form method="POST" action="${root}/create.do">
    <table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="10">
            <c:forEach var="seatlessEmployee" items="${seatlessEmployeesList}" varStatus="loopCount">
         <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>${seatlessEmployee.employeeID }</td>
                <td>${seatlessEmployee.firstName }</td>
                <td>${seatlessEmployee.lastName }</td>
                <td>
                    <select name="emptySeatID">
                        <c:forEach var="emptySeat" items="${emptySeatsList}">
                          <option value="${emptySeat.seatID }">${emptySeat.seatName }
                        </c:forEach>    
                     </select>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <input type="hidden" value="${seatlessEmployee.employeeID }" name="seatlessEmployeeID"/>
                        <input type="submit" value="Create"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </c:forEach>
           </tbody>
        </table>
   </form>
```

Comment: this differs from the original layout semantics (a form for every row)

Comment: @wero yup because that was invalid layout.

Comment: there is no valid layout when you try have multiple forms within a table.

Comment: to clarify to "properly" obtain such a layout you would need to place the form inside it's own td and nest an additional table inside that td with the desired layout (really messy). Since the form action is the same across each element this would achieve a similar result with less mess/restructuring.